# c# unknown system variable lower_case_table_names

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, frameworks

I am preparing first application in C# .Net with is connected with mysql. Normally I used Embarcadero Delphi.

But I C# .Net Framework ...
I get the error: "unknown system variable lower_case_table_names"

- Mysql Connector 8.1.0
- MySql for visual Studio 2.0.5
- .Net framework 4.7.2

and bizarre is that in VS in Server Explorer I have Data Connection / database and I can see tables.

I used windows 10 , mysql 5.0.5 community NT via tcp/ip

my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Exper7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection cnn;
            string server = "127.0.0.1";
            string database = "database";
            string uid = "root";
            string password = "root";   //im using xampp
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + "; " + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in my.ini

```
lower_case_table_names =
```

```
    I tried 0.1.2
```

and nothings helps

when I put in mysql :> show variables
[image]

Comment: Why do you use a mysql 5.0.5? That version has never been publickly released, but even if it had be, that would have been 18 years ago!

Comment: I use this mysql because I have the same in server where is Production database and I can't change it.

Comment: Then I would use a mysql connector that was developed closer to that version.

Comment: Maybe I start with better mysql server - witch version You recomend - mysql , ODBCmysql , ODBC/net ?

Comment: If this is your production mysql version, then you better work with that, otherwise you may see other problems popping up with mysql.

Comment: Run a `show variables` utility statement on mysql and see if the setting is there,

Comment: Now is 1 but I tried with 0 and 1 and 2

Comment: The error says the variable does not exist, not that its setting is incorrect. If the server variable exists, then either the setting is misspelled in your code or the error is not raised by your code.

Comment: I add The screen from mysql query : show variables

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering [bug 96717](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96717), which is a known issue in MySQL Connector/NET: the latest versions (8.0.17 and later) are not compatible with old server versions.

MySQL Server 5.0 is extremely old (from 2005) and no longer supported.

Your possible fixes or workarounds include:

- Update your MySQL Server version to a recent, supported version
- Downgrade MySql.Data to an older, unsupported version that's still compatible with MySQL Server 5.0
- Switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) (disclaimer: lead author), which may be more compatible with older MySQL versions; NOTE: it hasn't been tested with MySQL Server 5.0, so it may also have compatibility issues, but in general it tends to have better server support than MySql.Data does

Comment: I think I change MYsql server. I just talk with boss about buying new one so I will have good time to install new Mysql and test a lots of connected elements

Comment: Can you hibe me numger good stable version mysql?

Comment: I would recommend MySQL Server v8.0.34.